# Linux login looping back to logon screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, login

From Gnome GUI (on ubuntu 12.0.4 classic not unity) I am able to authenticate from the logon screen: but after starting to load the user workspace, some error occurs - probably in /etc/profile since I have a lot of stuff there - and then we end up right back to the Gnome Login chooser.

When I did CTL-ALT-F1  - which is usually my savior in such circumstances - i get the dreaded "No Signal" on the monitor.  Now I am kind of out of ideas how to proceeed.

I just want a single-user shell to go and nuke the /etc/profile (and possibly ~/.bashrc as well).  How to get the single user prompt?

Note: this is NOT the same question as  [Ubuntu Server 12.10 - After entering credentials at login screen, the login screen reappears. Login screen is looping](https://superuser.com/questions/641695/ubuntu-server-12-10-after-entering-credentials-at-login-screen-the-login-scre)  That other one involves win2008/samba/etc. This one is simple ubuntu only.

**UPDATE**  I have reason to believe the issue is simply incompatibility with my monitor. **How to boot to VGA?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holding down shift during the entire bootup sequence did lead to a single user logon screen. And .. yes .. my /etc/profile was to blame for the issue.    Nuked it, restarted and all's well.

**UPDATE**  This process does NOT work on all machines. There is an onerous bug in grub: can not boot to it from many types of hardware.

I also have a good laptop also with Linux on it.  Finally i brought up my Mac with the HW codebase and dev env and am ready to roll.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/425979

This is a really bad showstopper. I may have to wipe that one machine since no apparent way to get to grub.

**Further update**  After about ten attempts, and spurred by one comment in the bug - I did manage to get to grub and chose Recovery Mode.  The trick is **hit SHIFT repeatedly**. Do not just hold it down.

Comment: @pnuts  I do go back to clean up unaccepted answers on some interval - so this one would have been marked within a week or so. IN addition, there would be the off chance that someone would come along with a BETTER answer. How about you??

Comment: @pnuts  Oh  I see - on this site I really AM neglectful . I do a better job on SOF.  So I "accept" your gentle commentary there. Will do some cleanup in a couple of days (under the gun right now)

Comment: @pnuts I cleaned up my list, thanks for pointing it out. Now only half a dozen questions with answers and unaccepted: in those cases the answers do not work and i have commented why. I had not done my housekeeping here.